# ERROR 1130 (HY000) not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server facing issue in granting permission

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I am trying to connect to mariadb running different container.Getting below error
$ mysql -u root -h test-mysql --port 3306

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'test_1_73f6dacd1d23.test_bluenet' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

Mariadb Server:
I tried the following
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;

```
+--------------+------+
| host         | user |
+--------------+------+
| 00a7a6a8d0af |      |
| 00a7a6a8d0af | root |
| 127.0.0.1    | root |
| ::1          | root |
| localhost    |      |
| localhost    | root |
+--------------+------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';

```
ERROR 1133 (28000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GRANT` statement doesn't work because the user@host combination `root@'%'` doesn't exist (yet). You can create it and then re-run the `GRANT`:

```
CREATE USER root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_secret_password_here'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The `WITH GRANT OPTION` part gives the user the power to `GRANT` privileges to other users.

Note that in order to be able to connect from the other container, you *may* also have to remove or comment out any restrictions in your configuration (i.e. files like `/etc/my.cnf`, `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/*.cnf`) such as any `bind-address` settings:

```
bind-address  = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment out with a '#':

```
# bind-address  = 127.0.0.1
```

... and then restart MariaDB.